# Drag'n'drop into console window

Tags: ruby, windows, drag-and-drop, console-application

Is there a way to get an object, dragged onto my console application using a mouse?
For example, a file or an image from browser.
Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Thought, you mean copy file contents, not simple paste of dragged object filepath?

There is [ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) (I'm an author of it) and [Far Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAR_Manager). This link allows to drag files into Far Manager panels from other GUI window and vice versa.

Short intro for Far you may read [here](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/FarManager).

For other console programs, running in ConEmu - simple paste of dragged paths occured.

**UPD**

About dragging to your own console app. There is a plugin [drag-n-drop](http://far-drag-n-drop-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/dragndrop/) for Far Manager worked somehow in plain console. The trick is to create invisible windows over console and hook mouse events (I had not dig deeper).

As for URL of dragged object - there is IDataObject::EnumFormatEtc wich allows you to enum all formats. For example, when I drag an image from FireFox, IDataObject contains (in addition) *.url file. You may take a look at [ConEmu sources](http://conemu-maximus5.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ConEmu/src/ConEmu/) for examples.

But, dragging image from IExplore may be some tricky. It does not work in ConEmu due IExplore zone restrictions. Don't know how to bypass this :(

Comment: Maybe not content, but some metainfo about it. Like as if it was an image from browser, I would like to get it's URL.